# Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Route>?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, jsx

**Am trying to link my car page so when clicked on it could go to that page but this error keeps on popping up saying jsx closing tag for route and don't know why it could be popping up as my tags are closed?**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Home from './components/home';
import About from './components/about';
import Car from './components/car';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>

      <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/">
              {create_page(<Home />)}
           </Route>
           <Route path="/home">
              {create_page(<Home />)}
           </Route>
           <Route path="/about">
              {create_page(<About />)}
              <Route path="/home">
                 {create_page(<Home />)}
              </Route>
              <Route path="/car">
                 {create_page(<Car />)}
           </Route>

         </Switch>

**Here is where I keep on trying to fix the code but it keeps on saying close tag for route yet route is already closed?**


  );
}

function create_page(page) {
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="header">
         <Header />
      </div>
      <div class = "page">
        {page}
      </div>
      <footer>
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </div>)
  }

export default App;
```

**This is the error that pops up**

Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for

```
</Route>

</Switch>
 ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the closing tag after the children of "About" route.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/">
              {create_page(<Home />)}
           </Route>

           <Route path="/home">
              {create_page(<Home />)}
           </Route>

           <Route path="/about">
              {create_page(<About />)}
            </Route> Here is the missing closing tag.

            <Route path="/home">
              {create_page(<Home />)}
            </Route>

            <Route path="/car">
              {create_page(<Car />)}
            </Route>
     </Switch>
</Router>
```